# Cant compile SDL source file with gcc

Tags: linux, fedora, gcc, c, sdl

i downloaded a manual of introduction to graphics programming with SDL, so i tried to compile my first source and it logged the next error

the command to compile it was:

```
$ gcc helloWorld.c [-o helloWorld] $(sdl-config --cflags --libs)
```

and the log is:

```
gcc: error: [-o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: helloWorld]: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use [ brackets ] in the command.  Try this:

```
$ gcc helloWorld.c -o helloWorld $(sdl-config --cflags --libs)
```

Comment: Please select the check mark next to this answer if it solved your problem.